# HTML5 MSE on iOS

Tags: ios, html, http-live-streaming, media-source

I'm trying to get hls.js working on iOS using Chrome Mobile, but I've noticed, that Chrome Mobile does not support the MediaSourceExtensions, which are definitely necessary!

Is MSE in any way supported on iOS ? (Chrome Mobile, Firefox Mobile.. ?)
If not, are there any plans to implement it ?

Answer (score 3):

As of Nov 2016 , MSE is not supported on [iOS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource).

However you dont need MSE to play HLS sources , [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) has native HLS support on iOS.

Comment: Update at Dec 2021, MSE is fully supported on iPadOS 13. Now only iOS Safari is not  available.